# Как найти путь к картинки при ее добавлении из галереи в ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на ImageView можно было загрузить картинку из галереи в этот ImageView. Метод loadInBackground() возвращает нуль. Как тогда по-другому найти путь к картинке? (На эмуляторе добавление картинки работает, а на реальном устройстве нет.)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        ivEditProfil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_edit_profil);

        ivEditProfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });
    }

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выберите изображение"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);

            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(new File(imagePath))
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(ivEditProfil);
        }
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader loader = new android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader(this, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

В методе `onActivityResult`, после того как инициализировали `Uri selectedImageUri`

```
final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            //присвоение вашему ImageView выбранной картинки
            image_view.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
```

И я думаю необходим пермишен в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```